# Parsing xml data in ruby using rexml

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using the glowfoto api and I'm trying to parse the xml data. It extremely simple, but I can't get it to work.

This is the XML data:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<getserver>\n <uploadform>http://img5.glowfoto.com/uploadxml.php</uploadform>\n</getserver>
```

How can I get that URL into a string using rexml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using REXML you can do it like this. REXML is included in the standard library

```
require 'rexml/document'

xml = <<-XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<getserver><uploadform>http://img5.glowfoto.com/uploadxml.php</uploadform></getserver>
XML

r = REXML::Document.new(xml)
puts r.elements["getserver/uploadform"].first
=> "http://img5.glowfoto.com/uploadxml.php"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was something extremely easy.